# Solving an identity

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve this identity using *Mathematica*:

$$3 \sqrt{5 \sqrt[3]{37}-16}=\sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]{b}-c $$

I know that `a`, `b` and `c` are positive integers. I want to find what `a`, `b` and `c` are. I tried

```
FindInstance[{a >= 1, b >= 1, c >= 1, 
3*Sqrt[5*(37)^(1/3) - 16] == (a^(1/3) - b^(1/3) -  c)}, {a, b, c}, Integers]
```

That did not work. I tried a few more approaches using `FindInstance` but with no luck.

Did I miss something or am I using the wrong function?

The answer is `a = 1369`, `b = 296` and `c = 2`.

Comment: does the equality return true if you plug in the known solution?

Comment: Narrowing the Domain it finds the solution `FindInstance[
 3 Sqrt[5*37^(1/3) - 16] == a^(1/3) - b^(1/3) - c && 1300 < a < 1400 && 
  200 < b < 300 && c == 2, {a, b, c}, Integers, 1]` but if `c>=1` the kernel crashes!

Comment: @george yes, if you wrap FullSimplify around it.

Comment: @tchronis wished I had prior knowledge of where a solution might be but I did not.

Comment: @bobbym I agree , I just was surprised about the kernel crash (I have Mathematica 9.0). I am not sure if FindInstance uses any clever algorithms in the case of integers - especially in nonlinear Diophantine equations.

Comment: Well.. if you need `FullSimplify` that is a clue why `FindInstance` isn't working.  Perhaps putting simplify ( or `Chop[N[..]]` inside `FindInstance` will do the trick.

Comment: @george I tried converting the whole thing over to Abs[LHS-RHS]< epsilon but that did not do it either. Also, do we know that FindInstance is the right way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would propose the following unorthodox approach for this specific :

Since `c>=1` obviously `a>b`

```
Catch@Do[
   c = N[a^(1/3) - b^(1/3) - 3 Sqrt[5*37^(1/3) - 16]];
   If[c == IntegerPart[c], Throw[{a, b, IntegerPart[c]}]]
   , {a, 1, 2000}, {b, 1, a - 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

returns `{88.341053, {1369, 296, 2}}` in my machine

Just to be sure a further check must be made to verify that this is indeed the solution (due to precision issues)

**Approach using fragments from Algebraic Number Theory**

```
(a^(1/3) - b^(1/3) - c)^2 == 9 (5*37^(1/3) - 16) == -144 + 45*37^(1/3)
```

`37` is a prime number so `a^(1/3)` and `b^(1/3)` belong to `Z[37^(1/3)]`.

`a=A 37^(2/3)` and `b=B 37^(1/3)` for reasons I won't expand here.

Instead we have to solve the following

```
  (A*37^(2/3) - B*37^(1/3) - c)^2 == 9 (5*37^(1/3) - 16)
  37 37^(1/3) A^2 - 74 A B + 37^(2/3) B^2 - 2 37^(2/3) A c + 
  2 37^(1/3) B c + c^2 == -144 + 45 37^(1/3)
```

Thus `B^2 == 2 A c` , `-74 A B + c^2 == -144` and `37*A^2+2*B*c == 45`

```
Reduce[B^2 == 2 A c && -74 A B + c^2 == -144 && 37*A^2 + 2*B*c == 45
 , {A, B, c}, Integers]
```

outputs

```
(A == -1 && B == -2 && c == -2) || (A == 1 && B == 2 && c == 2)
```

Comment: You can get slightly better bounds for your iteration by looking at the results of `Reduce[3 Sqrt[5*37^(1/3) - 16] == a^(1/3) - b^(1/3) - c && a > 0 && 
  b > 0 && c > 0, {a, b, c}, Integers]`

Comment: @belisarius very interesting! So `a>=15` and `b` is smaller than this sum of roots. Applying N I get a polynomial dependent by a. Maybe in larger search spaces (domains) this will help a lot!

Comment: Well,not much, really. `bMax` tends to `a` as `a` increases, so the gain is worth only when `a` is relatively small ;(

Comment: I notice that `1369^(1/3)==37^(2/3)` and `296^(1/3)==2*37^(1/3)` so a solution through Algebraic Number Theory would be appropriate.